# php completes execution first, then javascript runs

Tags: javascript, php

According to the main acceptance of the title, how do you explain the following:

```
       ...
       $temp1=$_POST['expert_id']; ?>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          var jstemp1 =<?php echo json_encode($temp1); ?>;
       </script>
       <?php         

       $temp1=$_POST['answers_id']; ?>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          var jstemp2 =<?php echo json_encode($temp1); ?>;
       </script>
```

Suppose $_POST['expert_id']=1 and $_POST['answers_id']=2. My thought is that $temp1 will equal to 2 when Javascript code begins to execute since PHP code executes  first. Therefore, jstemp1 would equal to 2 and jstemp2 would equal to 2. However, to my big surprise, jstemp1=1 and jstemp2=2. Can you explain that to me?

Comment: Because you've reassigned the value of the PHP variable `$temp1` from `$_POST['expert_id']` (presumably 1) to `$_POST['answers_id']` (presumably 2).

Comment: You did not see my point. When Javascript begins to run, $temp1=2, isn't it?

Comment: Nope - imagine you were writing **all** your JavaScript from PHP with echo statements; `echo <script type... blah blah blah> ... </script>` you're still pushing the code to the output buffer (screen) but the JS won't be executed as it's output (same as with just loading an normal HTML page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strip out all the JavaScript and you should see what's going on server side; you are literally doing:

```
$temp1=$_POST['expert_id'];
echo json_encode($temp1);

$temp1=$_POST['answers_id'];
echo json_encode($temp1);
```

So if `$_POST['expert_id'] = 1` and `$_POST['answers_id'] = 2` ...

```
$temp1=1;
echo json_encode($temp1);
// outputs 1

$temp1=2;
echo json_encode($temp1);
// outputs 2
```

So what you'll have client-side is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jstemp1 =1;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var jstemp2 =2;
</script>
```

**All** the server-side code (PHP) executes before the client-side code (JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

Your `PHP` code is inline with `HTML`/`Javascript` it will be executed first on the server, true, 
but the evaluation is be done in the sequence you have wrote it.

You assign a value to a variable, then print it out. 
After that you assign a different value to the same variable, over-writing it, then print it out.

This is perfectly normal.

Answer (score 0):

PHP executes the code in server side before the page is sended to the browser.

The browser receives:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jstemp1 =1;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jstemp2 =2;
</script>
```

And when the page is loaded javascript code is executed.